# How to search for Opportunities on VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I am trying to search for Opportunities on VF page based on some fields. 
My method is not getting any results.

Here is my code :

VF page :

```
 <apex:page controller="Oppsearch" showheader="true" sidebar="false">
 <Script>
  function doSearch() {
        searchServer(
           document.getElementById("stageName").options[document.getElementById("stageName").selectedIndex].value,
          document.getElementById("amount").value,
          document.getElementById("forecastcategory ").options[document.getElementById("forecastcategory ").selectedIndex].value,
          document.getElementById("status").options[document.getElementById("status ").selectedIndex].value
          );
      }

    </script>

    <apex:form id="frm"> 
     <apex:actionFunction name="searchServer" action="{!runfilterSearch}" rerender="test,in">
          <apex:param name="Stage" value="" />
                    <apex:param name="forecastcategory " value="" />
          <apex:param name="amount" value="" />
          <apex:param name="status" value="" />
      </apex:actionFunction>

      <apex:pageBlock id="test">                   


            <!--(Shows last 50 in reverse close date order)-->

            <table align= "center">
            <tr>

             <td style="padding-right: 100px;  padding-bottom: .5em;"><B>Amount</B> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <input type="number" id="Amount" value="{!Amount}"/>

  </td>

                         <td style="padding-right: 100px; padding-bottom: .5em; "><B>service</B> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <select>
                <option value="All">All</option>
                <option value="Service">Service/option>
            </select> </td>

            </tr><br/><br/>
            <tr>
                 <td style="padding-right: 100px; "><B>Stage</B> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <apex:selectList id="stage" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!Stages}"> </apex:selectOptions>
                          </apex:selectList> 
            </td>
             <td style="padding-right: 100px; "><B>Category</B> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <apex:selectList id="category" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!Category}"> </apex:selectOptions>
                          </apex:selectList> </td>
             <td style="padding-right: 100px; "><B>Status</B> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <apex:selectList id="status" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!Opportunitystatus}"> </apex:selectOptions>
                          </apex:selectList> </td>
             </tr></table>
             <br/><br/>
             <table align= "center">
              <td style="padding-right: 60px; "><apex:commandButton value="Opp Search" onClick="doSearch()" style="width:150px;"/> </td>
              <td style="padding-right: 60px; "> <apex:commandButton value="Clear" action="{!clear}" style="width:150px;"/> </td>


             </table>
            <br/><br/>              
            <apex:outputPanel id="in" >
                <apex:actionStatus startText="Updating...." id="outStatus">
                    <apex:facet name="stop">
                          <apex:dataTable value="{!Opportunities}" var="o" styleClass="list" id="dt13">
                                                   <apex:column >
                                <apex:facet name="header" > 
                                <a id="headr" class="headerStyle" title="Click here to sort">Opportunity Name</a> 
                                </apex:facet>   
                              <a href="/{!a.id}" target="_blank"> {!o.name}</a>  
                             </apex:column>  
                          <apex:column rendered="false" id="id"><apex:outputField value="{!o.id}"/></apex:column>
                          <apex:column headerValue="Account Name"><apex:outputField value="{!o.account.name}"/></apex:column>
                           <apex:column headerValue="Stage"><apex:outputField value="{!o.StageName}"/></apex:column>

                          </apex:dataTable> 

                     </apex:facet>
                 </apex:actionStatus>
                <br/><br/><br/>
            </apex:outputPanel>     
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
    </apex:outputText> 
</apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public class Oppsearch {


    public Opportunity opportunity {get;set;}
    public String soql {get;set;}
    List<Opportunity> opportunityList;

    Public String search {get;set;} //search text



  public PageReference runfilterSearch(){  

    String stageName = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('stageName');
    String amount = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('amount');
    String forecastcategory = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('forecastcategory ');
    String status = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('status ');
     soql ='select id,accountid, Account.Name,name, ForecastCategoryName,Amount,stagename,Status__c from opportunity';
    if (!stageName.equals(''))
      soql += ' and StageName includes (\''+stageName+'\')';

    if (!amount.equals(''))
      soql += ' and Amount >=  \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(amount)+'%\'';
    if (!forecastcategory.equals(''))
      soql += ' and ForecastCategoryName includes (\''+forecastcategory+'\')'; 
    if (!status.equals(''))
      soql += ' and Status__C includes (\''+status+'\')';
     soql+= ' limit 100 ';
      opportunityList = Database.Query(soql);
       return null;
       } 

      public void clear(){  
      opportunityList.clear();  
      }  

     public List<Opportunity> getOpportunities() {
           return opportunityList;
}

            public List<SelectOption> Stages
        {
            get
            {
                List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
                Schema.Describefieldresult result = Schema.sObjectType.Opportunity.fields.StageName;

                result = result.getSObjectField().getDescribe();

                List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = result.getPicklistValues();

                for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
                    options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
                return options;
            }
        }


            public List<SelectOption> forcastCategory
        {
            get
            {
               List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
                Schema.Describefieldresult result = Schema.sObjectType.Opportunity.fields.ForecastCategoryName;

                result = result.getSObjectField().getDescribe();

                List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = result.getPicklistValues();

                for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
                    options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
                return options;
            }
        }


            public List<SelectOption> Opportunitystatus
        {
            get
            {
               List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
                Schema.Describefieldresult result = Schema.sObjectType.Opportunity.fields.Status__c;

                result = result.getSObjectField().getDescribe();

                List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = result.getPicklistValues();

                for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
                    options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
                return options;
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: the inconsistent indenting of your code makes this hard to follow; SFSE etiquette is to put your best foot forward when presenting your code  -- think of the community as if we were your mother-in-law :-)

Comment: @crop1645 will keep in mind next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see following issues with your code.

- Opportunities is not defined anywhere in controller which you are using on your page. It should be opportunityList.
- Make opportunityList public

  ```
    public List<Opportunity> opportunityList{get;private set;}
  ```
- you are accessing forecast category, stagename inside javascript using id, they are salesforce component and Salesforece append parent component id for all child component. i.e. your category picklist id will be **j_id0:frm:test:category** so verify all component id.
- put return false to your onclick event  onClick="return doSearch();" it will prevent form post
- Check your all parameters you are putting blank space

  ```
  document.getElementById("forecastcategory ")
  ```
- includes is available only for multiselect picklist so your SOQL will update with in keyword

  ```
  soql ='select id,accountid, Account.Name,name, ForecastCategoryName,Amount,stagename,Status__c from opportunity';
  if (!stageName.equals(''))
    soql += ' where StageName in (\''+stageName+'\')';

  if (!amount.equals(''))
    soql += ' and Amount >=  \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(amount)+'%\'';
  if (!forecastcategory.equals(''))
    soql += ' and ForecastCategoryName in (\''+forecastcategory+'\')'; 
  if (!status.equals(''))
    soql += ' and Status__C in (\''+status+'\')';
   soql+= ' limit 100 ';
  ```

Though I am against the spoon feeding but as you have so many issues it is better to find understand the changes. I have not checked the SOQL but it will be great if you can debug SOQL and fix the issue around it.

```
<apex:page controller="Oppsearch" showheader="true" sidebar="false">
 <Script>
  function doSearch() {
        /*********Dynamic id generated by SFDC****************/
        /*********.value is used to get picklist value****************/
        searchServer(
           document.getElementById("j_id0:frm:test:stage").value,
          document.getElementById("Amount").value,
          document.getElementById("j_id0:frm:test:category").value,
          document.getElementById("j_id0:frm:test:status").value
          );
           return false;
      }

    </script>

    <apex:form id="frm"> 
        <!--***space removed from the end****************-->
     <apex:actionFunction name="searchServer" action="{!runfilterSearch}" rerender="test,in">

          <apex:param name="Stage" value="" />
          <apex:param name="amount" value="" />
                    <apex:param name="forecastcategory" value="" />

          <apex:param name="status" value="" />
      </apex:actionFunction>

      <apex:pageBlock id="test">                   


            <!--(Shows last 50 in reverse close date order)-->

            <table align= "center">
            <tr>

             <td style="padding-right: 100px;  padding-bottom: .5em;"><B>Amount</B> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <input type="number" id="Amount" value="{!Amount}"/>

  </td>

                         <td style="padding-right: 100px; padding-bottom: .5em; "><B>service</B> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <select>
                <option value="All">All</option>
                <option value="Service">Service</option>
            </select> </td>

            </tr><br/><br/>
            <tr>
                 <td style="padding-right: 100px; "><B>Stage</B> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <apex:selectList id="stage" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!Stages}"> </apex:selectOptions>
                          </apex:selectList> 
            </td>
             <td style="padding-right: 100px; "><B>Category</B> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <apex:selectList id="category" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!forcastCategory}"> </apex:selectOptions>
                          </apex:selectList> </td>
             <td style="padding-right: 100px; "><B>Status</B> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <apex:selectList id="status" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!Opportunitystatus}"> </apex:selectOptions>
                          </apex:selectList> </td>
             </tr></table>
             <br/><br/>
             <table align= "center">
              <td style="padding-right: 60px; ">
        <!--***return added to method****************-->
        <apex:commandButton value="Opp Search" onClick="return doSearch();" style="width:150px;"/> </td>
              <td style="padding-right: 60px; "> <apex:commandButton value="Clear" action="{!clear}" style="width:150px;"/> </td>


             </table>
            <br/><br/>              
            <apex:outputPanel id="in" >
                <apex:actionStatus startText="Updating...." id="outStatus">
                    <apex:facet name="stop">
                          <apex:dataTable value="{!opportunityList}" var="o" styleClass="list" id="dt13">
                                                   <apex:column >
                                <apex:facet name="header" > 
                                <a id="headr" class="headerStyle" title="Click here to sort">Opportunity Name</a> 
                                </apex:facet>   
                              <a href="/" target="_blank"> {!o.name}</a>  
                             </apex:column>  
                          <apex:column rendered="false" id="id"><apex:outputField value="{!o.id}"/></apex:column>
                          <apex:column headerValue="Account Name"><apex:outputField value="{!o.account.name}"/></apex:column>
                           <apex:column headerValue="Stage"><apex:outputField value="{!o.StageName}"/></apex:column>

                          </apex:dataTable> 

                     </apex:facet>
                 </apex:actionStatus>
                <br/><br/><br/>
            </apex:outputPanel>     
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Apex Class:

```
public class Oppsearch {

    public String Amount { get; set; }


    public Opportunity opportunity {get;set;}
    public String soql {get;set;}
    /************created as public list************/
    public List<Opportunity> opportunityList{get;set;} 

    Public String search {get;set;} //search text



  public PageReference runfilterSearch(){  
   /************mapping of fields from action function params************/
    String stageName = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Stage');
    String amount = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('amount');
    String forecastcategory = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('forecastcategory');
    String status = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('status');
     soql ='select id,accountid, Account.Name,name, ForecastCategoryName,Amount,stagename,Status__c from opportunity';
    /************where statement added************/
    if (!stageName.equals(''))
      soql += ' where StageName in (\''+stageName+'\')';

    if (!amount.equals(''))
      soql += ' and Amount >=  \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(amount)+'%\'';
    if (!forecastcategory.equals(''))
      soql += ' and ForecastCategoryName in (\''+forecastcategory+'\')'; 
    if (!status.equals(''))
      soql += ' and Status__C in (\''+status+'\')';
     soql+= ' limit 100 ';



      opportunityList = Database.Query(soql);
       return null;
       } 

      public void clear(){  
      opportunityList.clear();  
      }  


            public List<SelectOption> Stages
        {
            get
            {
                List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
                Schema.Describefieldresult result = Schema.sObjectType.Opportunity.fields.StageName;

                result = result.getSObjectField().getDescribe();

                List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = result.getPicklistValues();

                for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
                    options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
                return options;
            }
        }


            public List<SelectOption> forcastCategory
        {
            get
            {
               List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
                Schema.Describefieldresult result = Schema.sObjectType.Opportunity.fields.ForecastCategoryName;

                result = result.getSObjectField().getDescribe();

                List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = result.getPicklistValues();

                for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
                    options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
                return options;
            }
        }


            public List<SelectOption> Opportunitystatus
        {
            get
            {
               List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
                Schema.Describefieldresult result = Schema.sObjectType.Opportunity.fields.Status__c;

                result = result.getSObjectField().getDescribe();

                List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = result.getPicklistValues();

                for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
                    options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
                return options;
            }
        }

}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I added code  public List<Opportunity> getOpportunities() {
           return opportunityList;
} I forgot to add that in controller here , but still it is not giving any results

Comment: @Nani check the updated code.

Comment: "against the spoon" - that's an expression I do not know - is this the equivalent of "against spoon feeding" (American English idiom)?

Comment: @crop1645 yah I was referring the same but somehow missed that text (feeding) :)